# Configure Help option with commad that takes one argument in node commander

Tags: node.js, node-commander

How to configure help option the command in node commander that takes one argument.
Like, I have one command to add-repository as below:

```
program
  .command('add-repository <repo-name>')
  .option('-h,--help','help add-repository command')
  .description('configure your repository to do the respository specific taks')
  .action(addRepoCommandHandler);
```

Currently I can call the command by specifying the argument  and it is working fine. I want to add one option to add help option. That will show the help text when user calls the command with -h or --help option like: `add-repository --help`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default every command has a help option. So just take out your own help option and try using the one Commander adds for you.

You may change the default help flags and description using `.helpOption()`.

(Disclaimer: I am a maintainer of Commander.)

Comment: thanks. And as for my case, I can write `[repo-name]` argument as optional argument. And Now I can handle the `-h,--help` command in the handler